# Does Fantom support JSR-223?

Tags: jsr223, javax.script, fantom

Does the Fantom programming language, either directly or via a third-party implementation, support JSR-223?  That is, can Fantom be used to script Java objects via the 'javax.script' API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised that this question still has no accepted answer.  So, to answer it myself...

No - Fantom does not support JSR-223.  (As of 15 May 2015.)

There have been no further comments on the Fantom blog (re http://fantom.org/forum/topic/2127 or otherwise).  There appears to be nothing on the interweb re 'Fantom', 'javax.script' and 'JSR-223' as far as an implementation for Fantom goes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Fantom FFI](http://fantom.org/doc/docLang/JavaFFI.html) to use `javax.script` directly if you wanted - so possible, but maybe depends on what you're after?

Comment: Looked at FFI.  It defines a very clear mapping between Fantom/Java types - which suggests that Fantom would be a good language for JSR-223.

Comment: However, I'm not trying to script Java from Fantom, I'm trying to embedded Fantom into a Java servlet application which hands off requests to be handled by scripts in one of several languages (because I am experimenting with them).  I've got this working for Groovy, JRuby and Jython as they all provide a JSR-223 implementation.  Clojure should work too, as there is a third party JSR-223 implementation.  I'm wondering if this has been done for Fantom (either in the standard distribution or as an add-on).

Comment: Not sure I fully grok - but doesn't seem like it would take a whole lot - you got an example or something simple to illustrate?

Comment: Well, here is a simple JSR-223 example using Groovy: http://groovy.codehaus.org/JSR+223+Scripting+with+Groovy.  I've done similar things with each of Clojure, JRuby and Jython.  Since there isn't a JSR-223 for Fantom, I wanted to write one.  But there doesn't seem to be a appropriate Fantom method/class that provides all that is needed.  For example: How can I 'bind' variables for a Fantom 'script' to use?  Can I actually write a 'script' rather than a class in Fantom?  How can I get the return value from the script?